# How to avoid call-stack attack in the case of absence of EIP-150?

Tags: solidity, callstack, evm

While before EIP-150, could we avoid the call-stack attack by checking return value, of low-level functions .send(), .call(), .delegatecall() and .staticcall(), whether is false or not?

For example (msg.sender is a contract):

```
...
msg.sender.send(amount);
...
```

changing to:

```
...
if(!msg.sender.send(amount)) revert Error("Call failed!");
...
```

Whole contract in:
https://hackernoon.com/smart-contract-attacks-part-2-ponzi-games-gone-wrong-d5a8b1a98dd8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: Nope. Because, in this attack, call-stack slots are filled before execution reaches return of calling contract.
A way of preventing could be calculating expected amount of required gas for called function; setting the gas amount of calling function with respect to this.